# How to get the username of windows authenticated user in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, windows-authentication, impersonation

I have an single page application running in our Intranet. Users are authenticated by Windows Authentication (their domain-user). When clicking a button I want to send a request (using $http, Angular) to an aspx-page that has the following code:

```
        string result = "Unknown";
        var loggedOnUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        if (loggedOnUser != null) {
            int index = loggedOnUser.Name.LastIndexOf("\\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
            result = loggedOnUser.Name.Substring(index);
        }
        var json = "{ \"User\" : \"" + result + "\"}";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        Response.Write(json);
        Response.End();
```

This code only gives me the name of the user that is registered in the Application Pool. Thats not very surprising indeed so I guess I need to do some impersionating here? The reason for doing this is that I want the username in my javascript so that it can be sent as a paramter in other calls to the server.
I have searched the web and everyone says that getting the logged-in users username is a big security breach. And I do see that. But I may be a workaround when it is done in a way that involve server-code?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're sending the username as a parameter in other calls, what's there to stop an educated user from replacing that username with someone else's? Your authentication should happen on each call.

Comment: And on a second note, what are your site's authentication settings? Are you allowing anonymous auth?

Comment: This is an Intranet-application with users with good intensions so security is not an issue. I can ask the user to type in his domain-username or create a login-form or something like that and the issue would be solved. I just want to make it easy for my coworkers so they log in once with the Windows-domain-user account. Windows Authentication is set in IIS.Anonymous access is not allowed by now. I'll take any hack that works ok, after all it is all internal and behind firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

I got like this on `Login` click

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string UserName = "";
            string activeDomain = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
            string strName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();


            if (strName == "")
            {
                UserName = activeDomain;
            }
            else
            {
                UserName = strName;
            }

            if (UserName == "")
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Invalid Credentials. Please contact administrator!";
            }
            else
            {
                LP.UserName = UserName;
                DataSet dsUserName = LBLL.validate_user(LP);
                if (dsUserName.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Session["UserName"] = dsUserName.Tables[0].Rows[0]["userName"].ToString();
                    Session["entityUID"] = dsUserName.Tables[0].Rows[0]["entityUID"].ToString();
                    Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx", false);
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Invalid Credentials. Please contact administrator!";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```